# I have a 256*256 image for which I have to generate a 256*256 size histogram

Tags: c, image-processing, histogram

This means that the highest frequency I can show in my histogram for a pixel value will be 256 (256 pixels in a column). So, I need help  mapping the pixel counts to [0,255].
I have already tried dividing all the pixel counts by 256 so that they all come under the range but this meant that those with pixel values less than 256 turned to 0.

Comment: A logarithmic Y axis might work better for this.

Comment: In a 24bpp picture, pixels have values 256x256x256. How do what to map that to 256?

Comment: It's a grayscale image @PaulOgilvie

Comment: @MarkRansom this seems like a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: Force it to show `1` when there is *any* occurrence of a pixel value with `ceil`, or at the least, `round` the divided count, then pixel counts of 128 will show up.

Comment: @MarkRansom there are some pixels which have zero frequency in which case log(0) would not favor the task.

Comment: @WeatherVane can you please elaborate?

Comment: @MarkRansom I took care of it. I just simply ignored those pixels. However, I need to implement some code so that I can magnify these values.